# Regex: need to match a set of character and not match to another set of character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have two type of input,

```
str_1 = 'rb_done_1' 
str_2 = 'rb_${4}done'
```

I need regex to match true only one. My best try is :

```
reg_1 = '(^[a-zA-z0-9_]+[^{}$]$)' # returns true for 1 and false for 2, this is desired output
reg_2 = '(^[a-zA-z0-9_][\${}]+$)' # returns false for both case, should return false for 1 and true for 2
```

**^ .. $** is used to make a full string match. in reg_2 I am trying to match one or more character from **'a-zA-z0-9_'** and one or more from **'${}'** ( must have at least one to differentiate two type of input).

Comment: Do you want to match both with a single pattern or 2 patterns?

Comment: reg_1 should show true for 1 and false for 2
 vice versa for reg_2. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Do you mean this for 1 `^\w+$` https://regex101.com/r/rxsYq7/1 and this `^(?=.*[${}])(?=.*\w)[\w${}]+$` for 2 https://regex101.com/r/IXKap4/1

Comment: yes! Wow! I will check for some more input but usually inputs always have this two type of features. 
Please add this as an answer. Thanks! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have added an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the patterns you tried

- The first pattern `^[a-zA-z0-9_]+[^{}$]$` matches the first string because the last part `[^{}$]` is a negated character class which will match any char except what is listed in the character class.

  That means that the 1 at the end of `rb_done_1` will be matched by `[^{}$]`
- The second pattern `^[a-zA-z0-9_][\${}]+$` does not match both, because the character class at the start does not have a quantifier but the second one has, meaning that the second character of the string until the end has to be one of `$` `{` or `}`

**Note** that `A-z` [is not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) as `A-Za-z`

---

For the first string you could match 1+ times a word character.

```
^\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rxsYq7/1)

---

For the second string you could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to make sure there is at least a single char `$` `{` or `}` and make sure that there is at least a single word character

```
^(?=.*[${}])(?=.*\w)[\w${}]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IXKap4/1)

Or use negated character classes which is more efficient but a slightly longer pattern

```
^(?=[^${}\r\n]*[${}])(?=[^\w\r\n]*\w)[\w${}]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJGzFe/1)